# Sending a Collection of requests for Distance matrix in android

Tags: android, json, google-maps

### **I am looking at the** [GOOGLE DISTANCE MATRIX](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

---

- I read the docs and i could understand clearly that we need to send
  `latitude` & `Longitude` of `source` and `destination` to the URL `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/output?parameters`
- Output will be the JSON, then we ned to parse it and get the distance
  value

---

**My Question**::

- So this makes us to send individual requests and parse each one of
  them when a collection of requests is involved
- So can i send 10 lat & long of source and destination at once and
  recieve the JSON response as a single object ?
- If possible how ?
- Any examples to learn ?

Comment: I don't think that its possible to send one more than Lat/Lang in a single request

Comment: @ Pankaj .... Making multiple requests instead of one is costly in terms of resource right ? .... any other methods to achieve distance ?

Comment: ohh Damn i'm really sorry !!! yes its possible ofcourse

Comment: try this request http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=12.919661,%2077.632464|12.925192,%2077.635984&destinations=12.921156,%2077.620598|12.937098,%2077.627006&mode=driving&sensor=false

Comment: its has 2 destinations and 2 sources

Comment: Yup! .... thanks for that  .... that was exactly what i was looking for ...... post it as answer ill accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it's possible.**
 Doing in this way, you can achieve what you are looking for:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=origin1|origin2|origin3&destinations=destination1|destination2|destination3&mode=driving&sensor=false

So you can set your multiple origins and destinations separated by **|**.

Then you need to parse the returned Json data in your app.

Answer (score 0):

### I want to add another answer Just for someone looking something similar

---

***How to get JSON data using `latitude` and `longitude`***

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&sensor=false
```

---